# Excel: Dynamic Sum offset when not zero but needs to stop until today

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, match, offset

I was struggling how to limit the range of my formula when a certain month like today's month is reached. In my formula it continues summing up the next four month after todays months. As in my example, I want to sum up the first 4 months after zero but only until today's month is reached. If there are less than 4 month lets say 3 months remaining until today's month then it should only add the remaining three month.
I need to limit the width but it should be always four and only it should become less than four month when it is less then current month.

| Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | Jun | Jul | Aug | Oct | Nov | Dec |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 2 | 3 | ---> 1st period= 14 2nd period= 13 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 2 | ---> 1st period= 3 2nd Period= 0 |

Better in the picture below
[image: Excel file]

For instance

For the first four months:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",
INDEX(A2:N2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:N2<>0,),0)))),0.0.1.4))," ")
```

For the second four months:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",
INDEX(A2:N2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:N2<>0,),0)))),0.0.1.8))
-SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",
INDEX(A2:N2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:N2<>0,),0)))),0.0.1.4))," ")
```

Both formulas go beyond the current month and capture all the date beyond like Nov, Dec etc.  and I don't know how to keep it at 4 months and only adjust it when the remaining months are less than four months

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first period in first row use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A2:$L2*(COLUMN($A2:$L2)>=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A2:$L2)/($A2:$L2>0),1)+4*(COLUMN(A2)-1))*(COLUMN($A2:$L2)<AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A2:$L2)/($A2:$L2>0),1)+4*(COLUMN(A2)))*($A$1:$L$1<TODAY()))
```

and copy to the right and down

[image]

the formula will work if the first row contains actually formatted dates instead of text

---

Explanation for first period in first row:

1. `$A2:$L2` returns array of values in given range:

   `{0,0,1,3,4,6,5,5,5,10,4,3}`
2. `AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A2:$L2)/($A2:$L2>0),1)` returns smallest column number which value is greater than 0:

   `3`
3. `4*(COLUMN(A2)-1)` becomes `4*(1-1)` and returns:

   `0`
4. so expression `AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A2:$L2)/($A2:$L2>0),1)+4*(COLUMN(A2)-1)` becomes `3+0` and returns:

   `3`
5. comparision `COLUMN($A2:$L2)>=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A2:$L2)/($A2:$L2>0),1)+4*(COLUMN(A2)-1)` becomes `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}>=3` and returns array of booleans:

   `{F,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T}`
6. analogically second expression `COLUMN($A2:$L2)<AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A2:$L2)/($A2:$L2>0),1)+4*(COLUMN(A2))` becomes `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}<7` and returns:

   `{T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F}`
7. third expression `$A$1:$L$1<TODAY()` compares dates in first row with today's date and in october 27 will return:

   `{T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F}`
8. so final expression we get `{0,0,1,3,4,6,5,5,5,10,4,3}*{F,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T}*{T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F}*{T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F}` which results into:

   `{0,0,1,3,4,6,0,0,0,0,0,0}`
9. from which `SUMPRODUCT` summs up:

   `14`

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works for the excel file I provided, but as soon I use it in another excel with changing parameters accordingly, I get 0. The file has a longer horizont of four years.  Could you explain the formula on hand? I used =SUMPRODUCT($A5:$AM5*(COLUMN($A5:$AM5)>=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A5:$AM5)/($A5:$AM5<>0),1)+12*(COLUMN(A5)-1))*(COLUMN($A5:$AM5)<AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A5:$AM5)/($A5:$AM5<>0),1)+12*(COLUMN(A5)))*($A$1:$AM$1<TODAY())). As I needed 12 months and it needs to be not zero ( there could be negative numbers)

Comment: @StudentGuess I checked your formula and it worked correctly, so the problem is most likely with dates - they are entered as text. See explanations of the formula in the edit.